# Default inherited button text

Tags: vb.net, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

This is the code for my inherited Button control:

```
Public Class ButtonRefreshSmall
Inherits Button

Public Sub New()
    MyBase.New
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    Me.Text = ""
    MyBase.Text = ""
    Me.ResumeLayout()
End Sub
End Class
```

However, when I rebuild and drag this button to a form the text is always `ButtonRefreshSmall1`. I've tried variants without the `Inherits` declaration (since it's already in the `.Designer.vb` file, I've tried setting `Text` in Designer view/class of the control, to no avail.
Sometimes it won't even show in the Toolbox after rebuild.

All I want is for text of the button to be empty (since it has an `Image` defined in the designer).

This is what I have in the Designer file:

```
 <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'ButtonRefreshSmall
    '
    Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
    Me.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0
    Me.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat
    Me.Image = Global.TraxCashFlow.My.Resources.Resources.Refresh_grey_16x
    Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(23, 23)
    Me.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText
    Me.UseVisualStyleBackColor = False
    'MyBase.Text = ""
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub
```

And all other properties are set like I set them. I tried to trick it with `TextImageRelation` but the "B" is always visible anyway.

Update: Jimi gave me the idea in a comment below his answer, so I added a new `Property` `MyText` and this works just like I want (not sure why I need to call `Refresh` though, if I don't then it's updated after losing focus):

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class ButtonRefreshSmall

Public Property MyText As String
    Get
        Return Me.Text
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.Text = value
        Me.Refresh()
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    'MyBase.New
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    'Me.Text = ""
End Sub

<Browsable(False)>
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
Public Overrides Property Text As String
End Class
```

Update #2, see @TnTinMn's answer.

Comment: It might just be simpler to remove the text yourself after dragging the button.

Comment: [How to prevent winforms designer from setting Text property to instance name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791638/3110834)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish the goal you stated in a comment to the accepted answer,

> ... I'd want Text property to remain but just to be empty ...

You can apply a [ToolboxItemAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.toolboxitemattribute?view=netframework-4.8) to your custom button class.

```
<System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItemAttribute(GetType(ToolBoxItemNoDefaultText))>
Public Class ButtonRefreshSmall
```

This will tell the design environment to use the class `ToolBoxItemNoDefaultText` to control the creation of `ButtonRefreshSmall` for placement on the design surface.  `ToolBoxItemNoDefaultText` will derive from the [ToolboxItem Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.toolboxitem?view=netframework-4.8).

```
Imports System.Drawing.Design
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.Windows.Forms

<Serializable()> ' ToolBoxItems must be Serializable 
Public Class ToolBoxItemNoDefaultText : Inherits ToolboxItem
  Public Sub New(ByVal toolType As Type)
    ' this constructor is needed to allow the type decorated with 
    ' <System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItemAttribute(GetType(ToolBoxItemNoDefaultText))>
    ' to be added to the ToolBox
    MyBase.New(toolType)
  End Sub

  Sub New(ByVal info As SerializationInfo, ByVal context As StreamingContext)
    ' this constructor is needed to support the design-time deserialization of this
    ' class by the design environment.
    Deserialize(info, context)
  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnComponentsCreated(args As ToolboxComponentsCreatedEventArgs)
    ' this will run after all initialization code has run including that set
    ' by the component's designer, thus you can override designer set values.
    For Each comp As IComponent In args.Components
      Dim ctrl As Control = TryCast(comp, Control)
      If ctrl IsNot Nothing Then ctrl.Text = String.Empty
    Next
    MyBase.OnComponentsCreated(args)
  End Sub
End Class
```

This solution is somewhat after the fact as it allows the default designer code to run and then modifies the created instance.  You may notice that the `Text` set by the designer is momentarily displayed before it is set to `String.Empty`.

The proper way to deal with this would be to create a custom designer and not set the `Text` property during initialization. However, proper implementation of a custom designer can become involved if the user experience is to be as close as possible that implemented by MS.

Comment: See the update in my question, I think it's simpler.

Comment: @okkko, you may find it simpler for your needs, but if you ever need this behavior again. instead of one line of additional code to add the ToolboxItemAttribute, you need to replicate the the whole code pattern that you devised.

Comment: You're right! Tbh, I haven't really look at your code before but now that I've tried it, it works perfectly, no momentary Tex noticed. Upvoted and accepted as answer, sorry Jimi! I guess they are many solutions to simple problems.

Comment: Here is the designer approach: [How to prevent winforms designer from setting Text property to instance name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791638/3110834).

Answer (score 2):

That's just what the WinForms designer does.  When you add a control to the form, it sets the `Name` and `Text` properties based on the type of the control and the number of them that are on the form with default names.  It's done after the constructor is executed so your constructor code can't help.  You'd have to put code in the property itself to ignore a set in the designer:

```
Public Overrides Property Text As String
    Get
        Return MyBase.Text
    End Get
    Set
        If Not DesignMode Then
            MyBase.Text = Value
        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Note that that means that you won't be able to set it yourself either though, unless at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way: override or shadow the Text property, adding a [DesignerSerializationVisibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibilityattribute.-ctor) Attribute, setting it to **`DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden`** and the [Browsable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.-ctor) attribute to `False`.

The Designer won't generate any code for the Text property (so the Control won't show a text), the property is not visible in the PropertyGrid but it's still there and can be set in code.

```
<Browsable(False)>
<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)>
Public Overrides Property Text As String
' or
' Public Shadows Property Text As String
```

Another way is to remove the property, using a custom designer.
See here how it can be implemented:
[Is it possible to change the value of a property attribute at design time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56582658/7444103)

Comment: Both answers are good and a compromise at the same time. I'd want Text property to remain but just to be empty. For this particular case I accept this is an answer.

Comment: As I said in my answer, you wouldn't be able to set the `Text` yourself in the designer anyway, so hiding it in the designer is a better option.  You can still set it in code because, as this answer says, the property still exists.